# Unable to authenticate using REST Framework JWT

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I can successfully request a token, and include it in the header of the new request. However, when I try to access restricted views, I keep getting
`AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'successful_authenticator'`as well as
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InvalidTokenError'`

Here's my dummy restricted view:

```
class RestrictedView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )

    def post(self, request):

        response_data = json.dumps({"authenticated": "mooh"})

        return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/json')
```

The post method naturally doesn't start executing, since there's a problem with the authentication.

Here is the Authorization header of the incoming request after checking it in the Silk profiler:

```
"AUTHORIZATION: JWT iOjE0NDQ1NjQ...."
```

My settings.py contains the following:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'FORM_METHOD_OVERRIDE': None,
    'FORM_CONTENT_OVERRIDE': None,
    'FORM_CONTENTTYPE_OVERRIDE': None
}
```

I'd appreciate any help, as I've been stuck on this seemingly basic issue for a while. What does the error actually mean?

**Edit:** The original problem is solved, as answered below. Quite a silly mistake to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I just had to update my `PyJWT` installation to the latest, `1.4.0` version.

Comment: You should accept this as the answer then. This might help others facing the same issue.

Comment: I certainly will, I just have to wait 2 days before I can accept it.

Comment: @Marlyyy I am facing same issue, not getting user into request.user so can you guide me how to authenticate and get correct user object into request.

Comment: Same error occured at `PyJWT` lower than `1.3.0` version. `1.3.0` version or upper version will solve this problem